# Ordering without tie breaks

Tags: r, sorting

The function `order` in R returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order, breaking ties by further arguments. What I want is the permutation without tie breaks

```
set.seed(1)
b <- sample(round(rnorm(3),2),9,replace=TRUE)
b
#>[1] [1] -0.84  0.18  0.18 -0.63 -0.63 -0.63 -0.84  0.18 -0.84
# should be
[1] 1 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match`

```
match(b, sort(unique(b)))
# [1] 1 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 1
```

---

As mentioned by Jesper in the comments another option is

```
as.integer(factor(b))
```

---

Gregor mentioned `dense_rank` from `dplyr`

```
dplyr::dense_rank(b)
```

and `frank` from `data.table`

```
data.table::frank(b, ties.method = "dense")
```

but `match` is most efficient given below sample data

```
set.seed(1)
b <- sample(round(rnorm(3), 2), 100000, replace = TRUE)

benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  match = match(b, sort(unique(b))),
  factor = as.integer(factor(b)),
  dplyr = dplyr::dense_rank(b),
  data.table = data.table::frank(b, ties.method = "dense")
)

autoplot(benchmark)
```

[image]

```
benchmark
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval  cld
#      match  3.860337   3.992396   4.507669   4.408813   4.712448   7.77195   100 a   
#     factor 98.624234 100.011022 106.285972 103.896008 108.603783 147.02728   100    d
#      dplyr 22.824663  23.388366  25.112084  24.062046  25.720228  39.88105   100   c 
# data.table  6.370802   6.563733   8.854151   6.773746   7.476541  51.12899   100  b
```

Comment: how about `as.integer(factor(b))`? Seems to work.

Comment: @JesperHybelPedersen Included a benchmark and `match` is a lot faster (if that matters).

Comment: agreed it also seems a bit hacky.

Comment: See also `dplyr::dense_rank` and `data.table::frank(x, ties.method = "dense")`. If you care about speed, I'd bet on `frank`.